# How to use ffmpeg commnad in android with input and output file path?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I want use ffmpeg command in android app.i am using this library to start with ffmpeg.

http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/

i have developed a demo app and also run the command

ffmpeg -version

this command also giving exact ouput. but when i am giving any file path with name my command always fail for this i am using:

```
            String cmd[] = new String[]{"ffmpeg", "-i", "/storage/emulated/0/Videos/dheere.mp4", "-c:v", "libx264", "/storage/emulated/0/Videos/dheere2.3gp"};
            execute(cmd);




  private void execute(String cmd[]) {


    try {
        // to execute "ffmpeg -version" command you just need to pass "-version"
        FFMpegApp.getFfmpeg().execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.e("gc", "Command Started");
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) {
                Log.e("gc", "onProgress" + message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                Log.e("gc", "onFailure command" + message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                Log.e("gc", "onSuccess command" + message);
            }


            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.e("gc", "onFinish command");
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        // Handle if FFmpeg is already running
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

please give me any suggetion how to use command in android?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to all command with sing string and without ffmped word

Comment: can you give me example how to do, but this method taking only string args array.

Comment: Just remove ffmpeg from array

Comment: ok thanks krutik, now its working charm.

Comment: Mark comment as usefull

Answer (score 0):

```
private void execute() {
String[] cmd = {"ffmpeg -i input_file_path.mp4 -ss 00:00:00.000 -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 10 -s 320x240 -t 00:00:10.000  output_file_path.gif"}

try {
    // to execute "ffmpeg -version" command you just need to pass "-version"
    FFMpegApp.getFfmpeg().execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            Log.e("gc", "Command Started");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgress(String message) {
            Log.e("gc", "onProgress" + message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(String message) {
            Log.e("gc", "onFailure command" + message);
            // this will fail in case of wrong input or output path.
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String message) {
            Log.e("gc", "onSuccess command" + message);
        }


        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Log.e("gc", "onFinish command");
        }
    });
} catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
    // Handle if FFmpeg is already running
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```